BFU730F doesn't work on real experiment, what is wrong?
I have calculated BFU730F transistor on paper - all is ok.
I have created simulation for similar transistor (BFR740 because there is no BFR730) - all is ok.
I have maked shematics - it is not working. Out has 4.92V
I have tried  to replace Rb  to 2.2 k and to 47k - same, no current.
What i do wrong? Connections seems to be ok



Uhh, why a 44GHz transistor? What is the wavelength of one oscillation at even a quarter of that frequency?

what were you expecting to see?

i will not use him for such high frequency, maybe for 0.5GHz-1GHz, and now just test with an DC current. Can i do this kind of experiment with him?

I'm  expect to see some current between GND and Collector - and out voltage muss to fall to 3 or 1.5 or 0V depends of resistor R1

The BFU730 model works, there may be a soldering problem. The transistor side of the resistors should be wired with very short wires, because the inductance of the long wires will be huge. Here it would be better to use SMD resistors by soldering one half directly to the transistor. It is possible that you made a pretty good oscillator, we just can't see the signal.:)
The schematic below shows the DC values without input signal. The AC signals should not be taken completely seriously, as they do not include the inductance of the resistors and the stray capacitances of the assembly.
BFU730 Spice Model

In general, high-frequency circuits should not (and cannot) be assembled on a test panel.
It will never work.

"Should be wired with very short wires" -- More to the point, the lengths of solid wire: the probes going to the meter, even the resistor leads themselves, act as transmission lines and antennas over a vast swath of frequencies -- likely a source is not needed at all to observe AC signals on the breadboard!

Yes, there were a thousand other problems, I didn't think to detail them, as it was obvious that the author had never seen a working high frequency circuit before. The photo of the breadboard said it all. This is a special subject, you can't learn it here... It takes years of experience to at least to design a 1 GHz single transistor amplifier at least partially on the first try. The least interesting part of a high frequency device is the schematic. Even if it looks simple, if you haven't studied it, you will never be able to build it. Thanks.
